# Why is my total record count zero?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I can't understand why `compteTuples` is always `0.0` instead of `1003`, knowing that the table related to `_db.AppsMetiers` has 1003 rows.

```
private MonitoringDBContext _db = new MonitoringDBContext();
double compteTuples;

var model = _db.AppsMetiers
               .OrderBy(x => x.nomApplication)
               .Skip(nbLignesDepassees)
               .Take(nbLignesRetenues);

compteTuples = (double)model.Count() / 10;
```

Comment: try `compteTuples = (double)model.Count() / 10d;` notice the `d` with 10. You are doing integer division and hence the result. (missed the `(double)` with count). It is **not** integer division

Comment: What are the values of `nbLignesDepassees` and `nbLignesRetenues`?

Comment: @Habib, this is not an integer division. `Count` is casted explicitly, and 10 is casted to double being of narrower type in the expression

Comment: @Habib if one operand is double then it should be double division.10 will be promoted to double.

Comment: @Andrei, and Selman22, yes just noticed that. I was going to edit my comment, but now I will leave it for others

Comment: Make sure `model.Count()` is what you believe it is. right now, it's 0.

Comment: @User...have you checked in the debugger that the value of model.Count() is indeed 1003.  You may not be getting the records you anticipate

Comment: @user if `_db.AppsMetiers` have 1003 rows how could be `compteTuples` **101**? you need at least **1010** rows for this.also you are skipping some records...

Comment: according to your edit, my math is not so good but I'm pretty sure this will never equal to `1003` : `(1003 - someValue) / 10`

Comment: model.Count() is returning 0. Break apart your Linq query and check _db.AppsMetiers.Count() and _db.AppsMetiers.Skip(nbLignesDepassees).Count() return the expected number of rows

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the skip and take and compare your results.